# php preg_match on consecutive tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to capture all Location paths on an apache conf file, to make automatic nginx templates.

The file that I'm reading has something like this

```
<Location /images/mobile>
    SetHandler modperl
    PerlOutputFilterHandler Apache2::AMFImageRendering
</Location>
<Location /images/otherroute>
    SetHandler modperl
    PerlOutputFilterHandler Apache2::AMFImageRendering
</Location>
```

I almost got the regex working with the "location" match group, I had the following

```
$file_str = file_get_contents($conf);
preg_match("/<Location\s+(?P<location>.*?)\s*>.*?Apache2::AMFImageRendering.*?<\/Location>/s", $file_str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

The problem is this only get the first location "/images/mobile" inside $matches['location']

Is there anyway to match all locations, without splitting the string or using preg_match with an offset

Thank you

Comment: [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) sets parameter 3 to an array of global matches.

Comment: @SamSullivan thanks!, that works perfect, can you post that as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).  This is PHP's answer to the `/g` modifier of normal regular expressions.  The 3rd parameter passed (`$matches`) will now contain an array of global match sets.

```
$file_str = file_get_contents($conf);
preg_match_all("/<Location\s+(?P<location>.*?)\s*>.*?Apache2::AMFImageRendering.*?<\/Location>/s", $file_str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
// Array (
//   [0] => Array
//     (
//       [0] => SetHandler modperl PerlOutputFilterHandler Apache2::AMFImageRendering
//       [1] => SetHandler modperl PerlOutputFilterHandler Apache2::AMFImageRendering
//     )
//   [location] => Array 
//     (
//       [0] => /images/mobile
//       [1] => /images/otherroute
//     )
//   [1] => Array
//     (
//       [0] => /images/mobile
//       [1] => /images/otherroute
//     )
//  )
```